# Для чисел типов double,float,longdouble вывести на экран их внутреннее представление в памяти компьютера(dump)

Tags: c++

Как реализовать на C++??? Что стоит знать?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: формат дампа какой? их можно 100500 придумать

Comment: Что значит "вывести на экран их внутреннее представление в памяти компьютера"? Что именно надо вывести?

Answer (score 2):

Если в двоичном виде, то так:

```
double x = 42;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof x; i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << std::bitset<8>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&x)[i]);
std::cout << '\n';
```

В шестнадцатеричном - так:

```
double x = 42;
std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof x; i++)
    std::cout << ' ' << std::setw(2) << (int)reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&x)[i];
std::cout << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 3.1415;
unsigned char b[sizeof d];
std::memcpy(b, &d, sizeof d);

for (unsigned char c : b)
  std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned) c << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: но только memcpy не включена в std

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А точно? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) называет ее именно `std::memcpy`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, может быть, у меня другая информация, вполне может быть устаревшая. Но по моему она включена в std только в заголовочном файле  <cstring>

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: В С++ при включении `<cstring>` функция называется `std::memcpy`, но при этом `<cstring>`может опционально *дополнительно* объявить ее еще и как `::memcpy`. При включении `<string.h>` (deprecated) все наоборот: функция называется `::memcpy`, но при этом `<string.h>`может опционально *дополнительно* объявить ее еще и как `std::memcpy`. Так всегда было.

Comment: @AnT, а вот с этим я вполне согласен